# Clear overlay scatter on matplotlib image

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am back again with another silly question.
Consider this piece of code

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,x)
g = np.exp(-(square(X)+square(Y))/2)
plt.imshow(g)
scat = plt.scatter(50,50,c='r',marker='+')
```

Is there a way to clear only the scatter point on the graph without clearing all the image?
In fact, I am writing a code where the appearance of the scatter point is bound with a Tkinter Checkbutton and I want it to appear/disappear when I click/unclick the button.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return handle of `plt.scatter` has several methods, including `remove()`.  So all you need to do is call that. With your example:

```
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100);
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,x)
g = np.exp(-(np.square(X) + np.square(Y))/2)
im_handle = plt.imshow(g)
scat = plt.scatter(50,50,c='r', marker='+')
# image, with scatter point overlayed
scat.remove()
plt.draw()
# underlying image, no more scatter point(s) now shown

# For completeness, can also remove the other way around:
plt.clf()
im_handle = plt.imshow(g)
scat = plt.scatter(50,50,c='r', marker='+')
# image with both components
im_handle.remove()
plt.draw()
# now just the scatter points remain.
```

(almost?) all matplotlib rendering functions return a handle, which have some method to remove the rendered item.

Note that you need the call to redraw to see the effects of `remove()` -- from the remove help (my emphasis):

> Remove the artist from the figure if possible.  The effect **will not be
>   visible until the figure is redrawn**, e.g., with
>   :meth:`matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw_idle`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can you find what metods exist for a particular function like this one? On the pyplot doc, I only find the arguments, but not the methods...

Comment: Good question. On the [scatter docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) after the arguments list, it also describes the return type.  In this case, it is a `PathCollection`, and following through the links reveals that this class inherits from `Collection`, and then `artist.Artist` and `cm.ScalarMappable`.  Each of these adds several methods, and the `Artist` class is what provides `remove()`.  You can also find more in an interactive session with `dir(scat)`.

Comment: @MathieuPaurisse Also please be clear about the difference between the plotting _functions_ and the _objects_ that they return.